# TypeError: must be real number, not str

Tags: python

Whenever I rum the code, error message "TypeError: must be real number, not str" displays

```
from math import*

num1 = input("Enter the num ")
num2 = input("Enter the power ")

def exponent_func( num1 ,  num2):
     return(pow ( str(num1) , str(num2) ))  

exponent_func(num1 ,  num2)
```

Comment: You're casting the inputs to `pow` as `str`

Comment: It says should not be `str` and you are using `str()`.

Answer (score 9):

Use `int` not `str`

```
from math import*

num1 = input("Enter the num ")
num2 = input("Enter the power ")

def exponent_func( num1 ,  num2):
     return(pow ( int(num1) , int(num2) ))  

exponent_func(num1 ,  num2)
```

Comment: and what if someone wanted to get the square root of `num1`?

Comment: Then we would use  sqrt(x)

Comment: @Amy what if someone wanted to get `num1` raised to the power `0.1`? I'm not being pedantic here, but it's important to understand why what you did does not work and what the limitations of this answer are. **Edit**: It's also worth reading [Why is `import *` bad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2386714/why-is-import-bad)?

Comment: Well this is my first day into Python programming and I don't have much experience in programming so this was just to get familiar with the syntax. I have updated my code to use `float` instead of  `int ` Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 0):

You want to make the string inputs into floats or ints.`num1 = float(num1)`